# How do i make mobile responsive div which has text above select dropdown?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I have a row of 5 dropdowns and 5 labels above it .
It is looking fine with desktop version but worst with mobile version .

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:#0070dd;color:#ffffff;">
    <i class="fa fa-university"></i> Select Institute
    <select size="2" id="inst_all" style="width:200px;" multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectedCountries" ng-options="sort.Institute as sort.Institute for sort in products | unique : 'Institute'">
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:#0070dd;color:#ffffff;">
    <i class="fa fa-language"></i> Select Language
    <select ng-model="searchtxt" style="width:200px;">
      <option value="">Select Language</option>
      <option ng-repeat="user in products | filter:emptyOrNull | unique : 'Language'" value="{{user.Language}}">{{user.Language}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:#0070dd;color:#ffffff;">
    <i class="fa fa-eye-dropper"></i> Select Category
    <select ng-model="searchtxt" style="width:200px;">
      <option value="">Select Category</option>
      <option ng-repeat="user in products | unique : 'Categories'" value="{{user.Categories}}">{{user.Categories}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:#0070dd;color:#ffffff;">
    <i class="fa fa-headphones"></i> Select Instruction Mode
    <select ng-model="searchtxt" style="width:200px;">
      <option value="">Select Instruction Mode</option>
      <option ng-repeat="user in products | unique : 'Instruction_Mode'" value="{{user.Instruction_Mode}}">{{user.Instruction_Mode}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:#0070dd;color:#ffffff;">
    <i class="fa fa-building"></i> Select Accred. Institution
    <select ng-model="searchtxt" style="width:200px;">
      <option value="">Select Accrediting_Institution</option>
      <option ng-repeat="user in products |filter:emptyOrNullAC |unique : 'Accrediting_Institution'" value="{{user.Accrediting_Institution}}">{{user.Accrediting_Institution}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i make it look good on mobile version ?

Comment: What do you want it to look like on mobile, "looks good" is a highly subjective criteria. Also, while your desktop version may look fine locally I think you may have left out (some of) the necessary CSS from your post to recreate that look here in your question. I've added Font Awesome, and edited the question to use Angular 1.7.5 but even so, I think something is missing.

Comment: @David Thomas labels and dropdowns are still not proper.

Comment: I have no idea what that means; they're wrong? In the code of your website? In the question here? Somewhere else?

Comment: Everywhere , Their Alignment is not proper. @David Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can put the configurations for the layout you wanna use in mobile view inside a @media tag. The changes you put to your objects in this tag will only apply when its in mobile view. I left an example below.

Here is the CSS tag for responsive design:

```css
#example {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 

}


/* The (max-width: 820px) is for the computer to know at what viewport 
   width to apply the configurations.*/
   /* Here is the tag used for Mobile View: */

@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  #example {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }
  
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```